# Rails: change models default path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

my pb: I have 18 models, and I would like to split my 'models' folder in subfolder.
Is there a way to tell rails to look for models in subfolders ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its pretty easy:

Structure:

```
app/
  models/
    widgets/
      user_widget.rb
    user.rb
```

Models:

```
class Widgets::UserWidget < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

---

For the record, it also works the same way for the libs:

Structure:

```
lib/
  dsl/
    comments_dsl.rb
  tasks/
  graph.rb
```

Classes:

```
class Graph
end

class DSL::CommentsDSL
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your models structured like the following:

```
# /app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  has_many :bars, class_name: Foo::Bar
end

# /app/models/foo/bar.rb
class Foo::Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

You can access model `bar` via `Foo::Bar` and `foo` via `Foo`. Rails will automatically load any files in `/app/models`. So no necessary configurations required.